# compare value pixel with int

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.1

I have a `Mat Dist` (`CV_8U`) done by `distanceTransform`.

Now I have to check each coordinate of `Dist` is `> 0` and modify the value of another `Mat M = Mat :: zeros`

the code is

```
      int main(){
              ....

               for(i=0;i<Dist.rows;++i)
               {
                    for(j=0;j<Dist.cols;++j)
                    {
                   if(Dist.at<uchar>(i,j) > 0){
                     M.at<uchar>(i,j)=2;
                      }
                    }
              }
            ....
            }
```

but I error cv :: exception.

I looked in the documentation and elsewhere , I tried to change from uchar to vec3b . I modified the exception in visual studio 2015 but nothing .
Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `distanceTransform` does not return ad CV_8U, it is CV_32 as we can see in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#distancetransform):

> dst – Output image with calculated distances. It is a 32-bit
>   floating-point, single-channel image of the same size as src .

So the code should not read uchar, but float

```
...
if(Dist.at<float>(i,j) > 0.f)
...
```

In case you used the labels from distance transform, in the documentation we have the following:

> labels – Optional output 2D array of labels (the discrete Voronoi
>   diagram). It has the type CV_32SC1 and the same size as src . See the
>   details below.

So, in this case you should access it as an int

```
...
if(Dist.at<int>(i,j) > 0)
...
```

I hope this helps you.

By the way, maybe an epsilon value instead of the 0 will be better....